Diffeomorphism is Poisson map iff is symplectomorphism
(Silly question I'm afraid...)

Consider symplectic manifolds $(M_i,\omega_i)$, with Poisson bracket $\{\cdot ,\cdot \}_{i}$, $i=1,2$, and let  $\phi:M_1\to M_2$ be a smooth map. Prove that if $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism, then it is a Poisson map ($\{\phi^* f,\phi^* g\}_1=\phi^* (\{f,g\}_2)$ for all $f,g\in C^\infty(M_2)$) if and only if $\phi^*\omega_2=\omega_1$.

$X_f$ is the Hamiltonian vector field of a smooth function $f$.
For $\impliedby$, the formula $\phi^* X_f=X_{\phi^* f}$ leads to the surely mistaken
\begin{align}\{\phi^* f,\phi^* g\}_1 & =\omega_1(X_{\phi^* f},X_{\phi^* g})\\
&=\phi^* \omega_2(X_{\phi^* f},X_{\phi^* g})\\
&=\omega_2(\phi_* X_{\phi^* f},\phi_* X_{\phi^* g})\\
&=\omega_2(\phi_* \phi^* X_{f},\phi_* \phi^* X_{g})\\
&=\omega_2(X_f,X_g)\\
&=\{f,g\}_2
\end{align}
For $\implies$, if I choose two vector fields in $M_1$ that are Hamiltonian vector fields of the form $X_{\phi^* f}$ for $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(M_2)$ I get that
\begin{align}\omega_1(X_{\phi^* f},X_{\phi^* g})&=\{\phi^* f,\phi^* g \}_1 \\
&= \phi^* \{f,g\}_2\\
&=\phi^* \big( \omega_2(X_f,X_g) \big)\\
&=\omega_2(X_f,X_g) \circ \phi
\end{align}
But that's not really what I want... and I understand not all vector fields in $M_1$ can be written that way. Thank you!

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction, you want to prove that at any point $p\in M_1$, $(\phi^*\omega_2)_p = (\omega_1)_p$. So take $u_p, v_p\in T_pM$ arbitrary. Then there exist functions $f, g\in C^\infty(M_1)$ such that $(X_f)_p = u_p, (X_g)_p = v_p$ (this is the step you were confused about - you only need to pick Hamiltonian vector fields that agree with your vectors $u_p, v_p$ at the point $p$). Hence
$$
(\phi^*\omega_2)_p(u_p,v_p) = ((\phi^*\omega_2)(X_f,X_g))(p) = (\phi^*(\omega_2(\phi_*X_f,\phi_*X_g))(p) = (\omega_2(X_{\phi_*f},X_{\phi_*g}))(\phi(p)) \\
= \lbrace \phi_*f, \phi_*g\rbrace_2(\phi(p)) = (\phi_*\lbrace f,g\rbrace_1)(\phi(p)) = \lbrace f,g\rbrace_1(p) = (\omega_1(X_f,X_g))(p) = (\omega_1)_p(u_p,v_p),
$$
i.e. $(\phi^*\omega_2)_p = (\omega_1)_p$. Since this is true for any point $p\in M_1$, it follows that $\phi^*\omega_2 = \omega_1$.

Whoa thank you! I missed that the pullback is not only applying the pushforward on the vectors but also evaluating on the image of the point. How can we make sure that the functions $f$ and $g$ exist?

Since $\omega_p$ is non-degenerate, it's equivalent to saying every $\alpha_p \in (T^*M_1)_p$ can be written as $(df)_p$ for some $f$.

Why does non-degenerateness imply this?

Non-degeneracy of $\omega$ implies the existence of an isomorphism $\tilde\omega_p:(T M_1)_p \to (T^*M_1)_p$ given by $\tilde\omega_p(u_p) := \omega_p(u_p,\cdot)$. Then $X_f = (\tilde\omega)^{-1}(df)$, and so the statement follows. This will be explained in essentially every introductory textbook on symplectic geometry, so if you're still confused, I would look there.

That makes sense! Thanks again!
